# I lost my files in a cut and paste. How to restore?

Tags: hard-drive, files, data-recovery

So earlier today I lost some very valuable files by accidentally cutting and pasting it instead of copying and pasting while trying to back up my files. I tried copying and pasting too but it didnt copy and paste as well, my files were just gone  after I went out to spend the time it took to paste.

This was my 3rd time trying to back them up, and some of the files transfered while some others were not there at all. Not in my disk, not in my external hard drive, nowhere. I tried test disk but the interface was too complicated, and trying to enable hidden files doesn't do anything.

Any help? No one in my town knows anything about Ubuntu OR Linux, so I am in big trouble if I cannot get my files back. Thank you.

Comment: I have checked that.  Not of any help, mostly.

Comment: It is doubtful that you have tried ALL the methods linked above, or you would likely have your files back already. Please edit your question to explain clearly exactly which methods you tried, which failed, exactly how they failed (no data? error message? something else?), and which methods you didn't try because you did not understand.

Comment: “I tried test disk but the interface was too complicated” It isn't. It's a step by step process. And, even if it was complicated, it would be worth the effort if you value your files. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)